# How to fix Swift enum switch case problem

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, swift4.2

Let's say we have this enum and some function that switch throw enum itself.

```
import UIKit


enum DumbTest {
    case get(user: String)
    case get(pony: String, tail: String)

    func getSome() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .get(let user):
            return "User muchacha \(user)"
        case .get(let pony, let tail):
            return "Fluttershy \(pony) with \(tail) tail"
        }
    }
}


DumbTest.get(pony: "cute pony", tail: "pink").getSome()
```

But, it seems like swift doesnt understand that it different case's, shows warning like this:

```
   1. Case is already handled by previous patterns; consider removing it

   2. Case will never be executed
```

for this string

```
case .get(let pony, let tail):
```

Result for

DumbTest.get(pony: "cute pony", tail: "pink").getSome()
is

```
"User muchacha (pony: "cute pony", tail: "pink")"
```

There is [gist](https://gist.github.com/Maxatma/6618d92b845fc6ec6da909e081d9b357)

Why does it happen?

Comment: that doesn't even compile for me as you cant have enum cases with the same name

Comment: Seems it happens because enum cases is more like tuples, instead of functions names

Comment: @Scriptable well, idk, compiled for me and worked okay in playground. What swift version do you use?

Comment: Maybe insert a `break`

Comment: Do you intentionally use the same case name “get” with different sets of associated variables? That looks like a bad idea to me. Note that `DumbTest.get(user: "user").getSome()` makes your code crash, therefore I wonder if that combination is supported at all.

Comment: @MartinR well, it doesn't look "the same name" to me, because you know, if you create functions like this func get(user: String) { } and func get(pony: String) { }  they will be different. So, it is not a bad idea, just kinda confused me. Still, think would be nice have an answer to this question, somebody can have the same problem.

Comment: @ZaporozhchenkoAleksandr: In the view of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0155-normalize-enum-case-representation.md, your code actually looks valid (the cases have distinct “full names”), so this could be a bug.

Comment: @MartinR wow, thanks!

Comment: @ZaporozhchenkoAleksandr: I have asked the problem in the [Swift Forum](https://forums.swift.org/t/pattern-matching-for-enums-with-same-base-case-and-distinct-associated-values/19368), perhaps we'll get some insight from there.